# How to fix the postgreSQL uninstall?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I want to uninstall postgreSQL 10.5 from my windows10 machiene but I always get this errormessage saying it can't find the uninstall.dat even when the file is in the same folder.

[image: uninstall error]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try Revo Uninstaller. It worked for me.